# Redirect directly to the correct url with www and https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a problem regarding my website and my htaccess file. It redirects first to the http version and after that to the www version.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.nl
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mywebsite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I redirect directly without the extra step?

I tried this but it keeps redirecting me and gives an error message (too many redirects)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Do I maybe have to rewrite the above example to this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mywebsite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I did some testing and when I throw in this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

It gives me that too many redirects error. is this the culprit?

Comment: have tried to purge your browser cache ?

Comment: @Robin Yes, that didn't work. Other browser, or in private browsing, same message.

Comment: is it Laravel project?

Comment: what kind of server do you use ?

Comment: No Laraval project, it's a Joomla installation. I think it's a CentOS. Apache?

Comment: is it cpanel or  directly accessible server?

Comment: have you forced https in joomla in admin panel ?

Comment: Directly accessible. Yeah I forced the https, but I disabled that function, but it still gives me the error. Maybe I have to clear some caches. You guys think the code above has to work?